# What is wrong with this use of offsetof?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4

I'm compiling some c++ code in MinGW GCC 4.4.0, and getting warnings with the following form...

```
warning: invalid access to non-static data member '<membername>'  of NULL object
warning: (perhaps the 'offsetof' macro was used incorrectly)
```

This problem seems familiar - something I've tried to resolve before and failed, I think, but a while ago. The code builds fine in Visual C++, but I haven't built this particular code recently in any other compiler.

The problem code is the following template...

```
template<typename T>
class c_Align_Of
{
  private:
    struct c_Test
    {
      char m_Char;
      T    m_Test;
    };
  public:
    enum { e_Align = offsetof (c_Test, m_Test) };
};
```

Obviously I can probably use some conditional compilation to use compiler-specific functions for this, and I believe C++0x will (at long last) make it redundant. But in any case, I cannot see anything wrong with this use of `offsetof`.

*Very* pedantically, it's possible that because the `T` parameter types are sometimes non-POD, so GCC classes `c_Test` as non-POD and complains (and complains and complains - I'm getting nearly 800 lines of these warnings).

This is naughty by the strict wording of the standard, since non-POD types can break `offsetof`. However, this kind of non-POD shouldn't be a problem in practice - `c_Test` will not have a virtual table, and no run-time trickery is needed to find the offset of `m_Test`.

Besides, even if `c_Test` had a virtual table, GCC implements the offsetof macro using an intrinsic that is always evaluated at compile-time based on the static layout of that particular type. Providing a tool then whining (sorry, warning) every time it's used just seems silly.

Also, I'm not the only person around here who does this kind of thing...

[Answer to legit-uses-of-offsetof question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453393/legit-uses-of-the-offsetof-macro-in-c-c/1455192#1455192)

I *do* remember having an issue with `offsetof` for this kind of reason, but I don't *think* the problem was this template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add an example for those POD-types that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Georg - No point - I wasn't thinking straight. They had constructors and thus were non-POD. See answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Oops...

The issue *is* with the `c_Test` struct being non-POD due to the T type being non-POD. Here's a quote from the GCC manual...

> -Wno-invalid-offsetof (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>
> Suppress warnings from applying the
>   ‘offsetof’ macro to a non-POD type.
>
> According to the 1998 ISO C++
>   standard, applying ‘offsetof’ to a
>   non-POD type is undefined. In existing
>   C++ implementations, however,
>   ‘offsetof’ typically gives meaningful
>   results even when applied to certain
>   kinds of non-POD types. (Such as a
>   simple ‘struct’ that fails to be a POD
>   type only by virtue of having a
>   constructor.) This flag is for users
>   who are aware that they are writing
>   nonportable code and who have
>   deliberately chosen to ignore the
>   warning about it.
>
> The restrictions on ‘offsetof’ may be
>   relaxed in a future version of the C++
>   standard.

My problem is that almost all my T types have constructors, and are therefore classed as non-POD. I ignored this point as irrelevant earlier - and of course it should be irrelevant for offsetof in principle. The trouble is that the C++ standard uses the one POD vs. non-POD classification even though there are a number of distinct ways to be non-POD, and the compiler is correct to warn about non-standards-compliant use by default.

My solution for the moment will be the option above to suppress the warning - now I just need to figure out how to tell cmake to use it.

Comment: I feel guilty accepting this - maybe I should undo that and delete the question instead?

Comment: Its fine as it really answers your question - others might make the same mistake. There is even a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) that encourages this :)

Comment: cmake solution: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-invalid-offsetof")`