# Pointer manipulation to access elements in a struct

Tags: c, struct

Given the below simple code, where you have process_payload is given a pointer to the payload portion of the packet, how do you access the header portion? Ideally the caller should simply give a pointer to full packet from beginning, but there are cases where you don't have the beginning of the message and need to work backwards to get to the header info. I guess this question becomes a understanding of walking through the memory layout of a struct.

The header computes to 8 bytes with sizeof operation. I assume Visual C++ compiler added 3 bytes padding to header.
The difference between pptr and pptr->payload is decimal 80 (not sure why this value??) when doing ptr arith (pptr->payload - pptr). Setting ptr = (struct Packet*)(payload - 80) works but seems more a hack. I don't quite understand why subtracting sizeof(struct header) doesn't work.

Thanks for any help you can give.

```
struct Header
{
    unsigned char id;
    unsigned int size;
};

struct Packet
{
    struct Header header;
    unsigned char* payload;
};


void process_payload(unsigned char* payload);

int main()
{
    struct Packet* pptr = (struct Packet*)malloc(sizeof(struct Packet));
    pptr->payload = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*10);

    process_payload(pptr->payload);

    return 1;
}

// Function needs to work backwards to get to header info. 
void process_payload(unsigned char* payload)
{
    // If ptr is correctly setup, it will be able to access all the fields
    // visible in struct Packet and not simply payload part.
    struct Packet* ptr;

    // This does not work when intuitively it should?
    ptr = (struct Packet*)(payload - sizeof(struct Header));
 }
```

Comment: Check the (non-standard) `container_of` macro, which you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455365/c-pointer-arithmetic-without-object-of-structure/21455524#21455524)

Comment: `pptr` in `main()` is rather pointless in this code. It seems to me you are trying (and not succeeding) to craft a [*flexible array member*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047530/flexible-array-member-in-c-structure) for the actual payload.

Comment: As WhozCraig said, you must be trying to do something : I cant see the point of not passing directly a `struct Packet *` to `process_payload()`

Comment: you may want to initialize your struct after malloc or use calloc, in your snippet they are left uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in `main` you allocate *two* pointers, and pass the second pointer to the `process_payload` function. The two pointers are not related.

There are two ways of solving this problem, where both include a single allocation.

The first solution is to used so called *flexible arrays*, where you have an array member last in the structure without any size:

```
struct Packet
{
    struct Header header;
    unsigned char payload[];
};
```

To use it you make one allocation, with the size of the structure plus the size of the payload:

```
struct Packet *pptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Packet) + 10);
```

Now `pptr->payload` is handled like a normal pointer pointing to 10 unsigned characters.

Another solution, which is a mix of your current solution and the solution with flexible arrays, is to make one allocation and make the `payload` pointer to point to the correct place in the single allocated memory block:

```
struct Packet
{
    struct Header header;
    unsigned char *payload;
};

// ...

struct Packet *pptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Packet) + 10);
pptr->payload = (unsigned char *) ((char *) pptr + sizeof(struct Packet);
```

Note that in this case, to get the `Packet` structure from the `payload` pointer, you have to use `sizeof(Packet)` instead of only `sizeof(Header)`.

---

Two things to note about the code above:

1. I [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
2. `sizeof(char)` (and also the size of `unsigned char`) is specified to always be one, so no need for `sizeof`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've seen the flexible pointers before, but was never really sure about why that was. Now I see. Thanks for the notes as well.