# Offset from member pointer without temporary instance

Tags: c++

I would like to get the offset of a standard layout member variable when provided with a poiner to that variable. I cannot use `offsetof` since I have a pointer and not a name.  The current code I have looks something like this, and I am wondering if there is a standards compliant way to get rid of the `dummy` variable.

```
template<class T>
struct {
  ptrdiff_t get_offset( int (T::*mem) )
  {
    T dummy;
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(dummy.*mem)) 
      - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dummy);
  }
};
```

This function should only be callable with `int` member variable points (this is intentional).

I am quite certain that the compiler doesn't actually create the `dummy` variable but it'd still be nice if I could get rid of it. I can't use a null pointer since dereferencing null is not defined (though it probably works on all common compilers). A C++03 solution would be good, or a C++11 solution is also of interest (but not usable by me now).

*NOTE: I'm already aware this is only standards compliant is T is a standard layout type.*

Comment: The return type should be `ptrdiff_t`, I suppose, and you should use `std::distance`. And the function should be `static`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes. I compile with full/extra warnings in GCC but I guess `size_t == ptrdiff_t`, so no warnings.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is signed... anyway, the `dummy` should also be static I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why `std::distance`? The subtraction and `std::distance` are the same here (§24.4.4/4).

Comment: @KerrekSB, function is not static in this case since my full function is not just a utility function but a true member function. I'd also avoid `static T dummy` since that might trip up compiler optimizations (as static often must be handled diffently, though here we might still be okay)

Comment: The implementation of `offsetof` macro involves dereferencing null pointer, btw

Comment: @Andrey, but that's an implementation detail and could be different in each compiler.

Comment: Another small improvement would be to use something like [Boost.AddressOf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof), to ensure that this works for types with overloaded `operator&`.

Comment: @Andrey: Not in gcc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400116/what-is-the-purpose-and-return-type-of-the-builtin-offsetof-operator

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
template<class T>
struct {
  ptrdiff_t get_offset( int (T::*mem) )
  {
    union {
      int used;
      T unused;
    } dummy;
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(dummy.unused.*mem)) 
      - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dummy.unused);
  }
};
```

The address of a union member doesn't depend on the union member being constructed. Works already in C++03, but then only for PODs.

Comment: So this version bascially eliminates any call to `T::T()` and `T:~T()`. It still has a dummy, but the abstract machine executes less code.

Comment: Well, obviously you need the memory, else you can't form the pointers.

Comment: This is still UB, as you are using a component of a `union` that was not active at the point of use.  As such, how is it better than `reinterpret_cast<T*>(nullptr)`?  It is worse in that you end up creating a bunch of stack room for the `T`.  There could be a system on which this works but the `nullptr` does not, but the other way around could be true as well.

Comment: @Yakk: Which exact bit would be "using a component of the union that's not active"? Remember that I may (must) form an lvalue to an inactive member in order to make it active. I.e. `dummy.unused = T()` writes to an inactive member, to make it active. I can't _read_ from an inactive member.

Comment: @msalters `(dummy.unused.*mem` -- I would be suspicious of that.  I should standard delve before condemning it, but... do you have a justification why it is defined behaviour?

Comment: Well, that's a perfectly reasonable lvalue to which you can write a new integer, which of course would make `unused` used/active. Deep down, the thing which breaks when reading inactive union members is the `lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` (or `glvalue-to-prvalue conversion` per footnote 53). But we don't have that conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that no standard-compliant solution which satisfies OP requirements exists.

I can give a couple of non-compliant ones.

```
template<class T>
  size_t get_offset( int (T::*mem) )
    {
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(((T*)nullptr)->*mem))-reinterpret_cast<char*>(nullptr);
    }
```

It's funny, but the following works in VC2010, making use of `offsetof` being a macro.

```
template<class T>
  size_t get_offset( int (T::*mem) )
    {
    return offsetof(T, *mem);
    }
```

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer via the `->*` operator. Consider the equivalent `(*(T*)nullptr).*mem`

Comment: You're still dereferencing a null pointer. Just because `offsetof` does it, doesn't mean that it's not UB.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: Yes, I know... I'm afraid that no solution which satisfies OP requirements exist. Either a dummy variable or dereferencing NULL is needed.

Comment: @Andrey, you can put "No" as an answer and if nobody else finds a solution I have to accept "No".  I already suspect there is no other standards compliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

So how about:

```
template<class T>
struct {
    ptrdiff_t get_offset( int (T::*mem) )
    {
        return 
        ( &reinterpret_cast<const char&>( 
            reinterpret_cast<const T*>( 1 )->*mem ) 
          - reinterpret_cast<const char*>( 1 )      );
    }
};
```

..?

This avoids both using a dummy AND dereferencing null. It works on all the compilers I've tried. The cast to char reference and then take the address (rather than take the address and then cast to char pointer) may seem unusual but it avoids a warning/error on some compilers.