# C++ offsetof char* arithmetic

Tags: c++, byte, language-lawyer

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33870348/650405), `int8_t*` is used for (byte) pointer arithmetic:

```
std::size_t offset = offsetof(Thing, b);
Thing* thing = reinterpret_cast<Thing*>(reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(ptr) - offset);
```

I've always used `char*` in the past but the comments are really confusing, and nobody responded, so I posted this separate question.

Is `char*` valid, and the preferred way of doing these calculations?

Answer (score 2):

You **must** use `char*`: the behaviour on using a `reinterpret_cast` with `int8_t*` on a pointer to something that is not an `int8_t` is *undefined*. Casting to `char*` can be viewed as an exception to the rule.

Pre C++14, `char` can be a 1's complement type with range -127 to +127. `int8_t` must be 2's complement. Even C++14 and onwards, I can't see why the types are related: `char` can still be either a signed or an unsigned type.

Comment: Regarding the pointer sizes, I thought all pointers to objects had the same size in C++. Is this not guaranteed? But whatever the answer, pointer arithmetic is affected by `sizeof(T)`, not `sizeof(T*)`. At any rate, the point about aliasing stands.

Comment: Your last point is correct: the sizeof(*) is not relevant so I've removed it as it only weakens the answer. As for your first point, I can't see why pointers to objects are relevant. We only have PODs here.

Comment: None of the first paragraph is true.  `uint8_t` is indeed not part of the special permission in the strict aliasing rule, but the pointer isn't being used for type punning here, only for pointer arithmetic.  The rules for pointer arithmetic are rather more permissive, and require only that the alignment is appropriate and the arithmetic doesn't take you outside the same complete object.... and there are no special permissions for `char*` there.

Comment: I disagree. You could end up assigning a pointer to memory you don't own, which, aside from one-past-the-array, is undefined behaviour. (And dereferencing `thing` will not end well.). Are you in a position to answer the question?

Comment: @Bathsheba “object” in C++ parlance means “memory location”. *Every* value is an object, and an object pointer distinguishes it from function pointer (and maybe `void*`).

Comment: Does anybody willing to write a proper answer?