# How to get a pointer to a containing struct from a pointer to a member?

Tags: pointers, rust

I have a type:

```
struct Foo {
    memberA: Bar,
    memberB: Baz,
}
```

and a pointer which I know is a pointer to `memberB` in `Foo`:

```
p: *const Baz
```

What is the correct way to get a new pointer `p: *const Foo` which points to the original struct `Foo`?

My current implementation is the following, which I'm pretty sure invokes undefined behavior due to the dereference of `(p as *const Foo)` where `p` is not a pointer to a `Foo`:

```
let p2 = p as usize -
    ((&(*(p as *const Foo)).memberB as *const _ as usize) - (p as usize));
```

This is part of FFI - I can't easily restructure the code to avoid needing to perform this operation.

This is very similar to [Get pointer to object from pointer to some member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870219/get-pointer-to-object-from-pointer-to-some-member) but for Rust, which as far as I know has no `offsetof` macro.

Comment: Why can't you just pass in a `*const Foo` to the C code instead?

Comment: In this particular example, the FFI is giving me a `*const Baz`, and I am expected to retrieve the original object from it. If I could simply pass around the original object, I would, but that is not an option.

Answer (score 10):

The dereference expression produces an lvalue, but that lvalue is not actually *read* from, we're just doing pointer math on it, so *in theory*, it should be well defined. That's just my interpretation though.

My solution involves using a null pointer to retrieve the offset to the field, so it's a bit simpler than yours as it avoids one subtraction (we'd be subtracting 0). I believe I saw some C compilers/standard libraries implementing `offsetof` by essentially returning the address of a field from a null pointer, which is what inspired the following solution.

```
fn main() {
    let p: *const Baz = 0x1248 as *const _;
    let p2: *const Foo = unsafe { ((p as usize) - (&(*(0 as *const Foo)).memberB as *const _ as usize)) as *const _ };
    println!("{:p}", p2);
}
```

We can also define our own `offset_of!` macro:

```
macro_rules! offset_of {
    ($ty:ty, $field:ident) => {
        unsafe { &(*(0 as *const $ty)).$field as *const _ as usize }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p: *const Baz = 0x1248 as *const _;
    let p2: *const Foo = ((p as usize) - offset_of!(Foo, memberB)) as *const _;
    println!("{:p}", p2);
}
```

Comment: Note: This currently does not work for statics and constants as [dereferencing raw pointers](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51911) and [casting pointers to integers](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51910) is unstable in these scopes.

Comment: Note: Unfortunately dereferencing a null pointer is (now) UB according to [RFC-2582](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2582-raw-reference-mir-operator.md), see notably the last section on **offsetof woes**. I believe that should this RFC be accepted, [my alternative implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40310851/147192) would be sound. Emphasis on *believe*.

Answer (score 8):

With the implementation of [RFC 2582, raw reference MIR operator](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2582-raw-reference-mir-operator.html), it is now possible to get the address of a field in a struct *without* an instance of the struct and without invoking undefined behavior.

```rust
use std::{mem::MaybeUninit, ptr};

struct Example {
    a: i32,
    b: u8,
    c: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let offset = unsafe {
        let base = MaybeUninit::<Example>::uninit();
        let base_ptr = base.as_ptr();
        let c = ptr::addr_of!((*base_ptr).c);
        (c as usize) - (base_ptr as usize)
    };
    println!("{}", offset);
}
```

The implementation of this is tricky and nuanced. It is best to use a crate that is well-maintained, such as [memoffset](https://crates.io/crates/memoffset).

---

Before this functionality was stabilized, you *must* have a valid instance of the struct. You can use tools like `once_cell` to minimize the overhead of the dummy value that you need to create:

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.4.1

struct Example {
    a: i32,
    b: u8,
    c: bool,
}

static DUMMY: Lazy<Example> = Lazy::new(|| Example {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: false,
});

static OFFSET_C: Lazy<usize> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let base: *const Example = &*DUMMY;
    let c: *const bool = &DUMMY.c;
    (c as usize) - (base as usize)
});

fn main() {
    println!("{}", *OFFSET_C);
}
```

If you **must** have this at compile time, you can place similar code into a build script and write out a Rust source file with the offsets. However, that will span multiple compiler invocations, so you are relying on the struct layout not changing between those invocations. Using something with a known representation would reduce that risk.

See also:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)
- [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423)

Answer (score 0):

Since Rust 1.77.0, the proper way to do that involves [`std::mem::offset_of!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/macro.offset_of.html):

```rust
unsafe { p.byte_sub(std::mem::offset_of!(Foo, memberB)).cast::<Foo>() }
```

Contrary to the previous (sound) way to do that, this is supported in const computations, and `offset_of!()` even supports (unstably) getting the offset of enums payload!