# Possible to access the 'TypeId' of a struct member?

Tags: types, rust, introspection

Is there a way to access the `TypeId` (`std::any::TypeId::of::<T>`) of a struct member by name?

If I have a basic struct:

```
MyStruct {
    value: i64,
}
```

And I only know `MyStruct` and `value`, is there a way to access `TypeId::of::<i64>` - where `i64` depends on the type of `value`?

```
main () {
    assert_eq!(
        TypeId::of::<i64>,
        // ^^^ this works
        type_id_of!(MyStruct, value),
        // ^^^ this is what I'm looking for
    );
}
```

---

See related question: [Is it possible to access the type of a struct member for function signatures or declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573055/is-it-possible-to-access-the-type-of-a-struct-member-for-function-signatures-or)

Comment: Maybe adding an example of how it would work can help. Would it be something like `TypeId::of::<MyStruct::value>`? Note that this syntax does not exist, but I think it serves as an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Added example to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use type detection to deduce the `TypeId` of any field of a value you have, as long as it's `'static` (other `TypeId::of` doesn't work):

```
fn type_id<T: 'static + ?Sized>(_: &T) -> TypeId {
    TypeId::of::<T>()
}

fn main() {
    let m = MyStruct { value: 4 };
    println!("{:?} {:?}", TypeId::of::<i64>(), type_id(&m.value));
}
```

Then, leveraging the strategy in the [`offsetof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823321/how-to-get-pointer-offset-of-an-enum-member-in-bytes) question you asked, you can make a macro to get it from a type without having an instance:

```
macro_rules! type_id_of {
    ($t:ty, $f:ident) => {
        {
            fn type_of<T: 'static + ?Sized>(_: &T) -> TypeId {
                TypeId::of::<T>()
            }
            let base: $t = unsafe { ::std::mem::uninitialized() };
            let result = type_of(&base.$f);
            ::std::mem::forget(base);
            result
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?} {:?}", TypeId::of::<i64>(), type_id_of!(MyStruct, value));
}
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't think it would be possible

Comment: @aochagavia: Once you know how to write `offset_of`, the rest is easy. It's not universal though because `TypeId::of` has this annoying restriction that `T` must be `'static` but I guess there's nothing *I* can do about that.