# Standard way to find base address of struct from a member

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, memory-address, offsetof

```
struct Data {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    float c;
};

std::string* allocateDataAndGetString() {
    Data* dataPtr(someAllocator.allocate<Data>());
    return &dataPtr.b;
}

Data* getBaseDataPtrFromString(std::string* mStringMember) {
    // ???
}

int main() {
    std::string* stringPtr(allocateDataAndGetString());
    Data* dataPtr(getBaseDataPtrFromString
}
```

I have a `Data` instance allocated on the heap, and a pointer to its `std::string b;` member. How do I get the base address of the `Data` instance the string is a member of, taking into account offsets and padding, in a standard way?

I've tried subtracting `sizeof(int)` and `std::offsetof(Data, std::string)` from the `std::string*` pointer, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: looks doable and... horrible. I would say just.. don't. Can you come up with a valid use case?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I'm using it for a (work in progress) bidirectional map implementation http://pastie.org/8752175

Comment: @Yakk Asuming that `ssvu::Uptr<Foo>` is a flavor of `unique_ptr`,  he's not using pointers to the elements, the elements *are* pointers. (I do note that `SneakyBimap::emplace` isn't exception safe - it will leak `pair` if `storage.emplace_back` throws. It's almost always a mistake to use an owning raw pointer.)

Comment: @Yakk, Casei: `ssvu::Uptr` is just an alias for `std::unique_ptr`. I don't undestand the *emplace mistake* - how can I fix it?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Put the raw pointer in a `unique_ptr` before passing it to `storage.emplace_back` (a la `storage.emplace_back(ssvu::Uptr<PairType>(pair))`). The easiest way is to use `make_unique` in the first place, so that the memory is always owned by some smart pointer: `auto pair = make_unique<PairType>(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...))`.

Comment: @Casei ah, I see.  So the only problem is presuming standard layout?  (`offsetof` supports non-POD in C++11?).  Probably `get2From1` should look much like `get1From2` (harmless almost certainly?)  I would replace `std::set` with `std::unordered_set` myself (unless you need order) and write `DerefHash<T>` -- much faster.

Comment: @Casey, thank you for the explanation. I have many instances of that issue in my codebase, will proceed to fix them all. @Yakk, what is `DerefHash<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `offsetof` from `<cstddef>`, but beware it is only defined on standard-layout types ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc3f84a73bc570ad)):

```
Data* getBaseDataPtrFromString(std::string* mStringMember) {
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Data>::value,
                  "offsetof() only works on standard-layout types.");
    return reinterpret_cast<Data*>(
      reinterpret_cast<char*>(mStringMember) - offsetof(Data, b)
    );
}
```

`offsetof` is detailed in C++11 18.2/4:

> The macro `offsetof`(*type*, *member-designator*) accepts a restricted set of type arguments in this International Standard. If *type* is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined.<sup>195</sup> The expression `offsetof`(*type*, *member-designator*) is never type-dependent (14.6.2.2) and it is value-dependent (14.6.2.3) if and only if *type* is dependent. The result of applying the `offsetof` macro to a field that is a static data member or a function member is undefined. No operation invoked by the `offsetof` macro shall throw an exception and `noexcept(offsetof(type, member-designator))` shall be `true`.

and C99 (N1256) 7.17/3:

> The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and
>
> ```
> offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by *member-designator*), from the beginning of its structure (designated by *type*). The type and member designator shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.`*member-designator*`)` evaluates to an address constant. (If the specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)

The "restricted set of type arguments in this International Standard" in the C++ standard is there to draw your attention to the fact that `offsetof` is more restrictive than is the case for the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

`offsetof` gives the offset in chars, so you need to cast to `mStringMember` to `char *` before doing the pointer arithmetic.

```
(Data*)((char*)mStringMember - offsetof(Data, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`offsetof` only works on standard-layout types.

There is a trick you might be able to use and does not require a standard layout: `static_cast` knows how to get to a more derived object from a pointer to one of its bases.

```
struct Data : private std::string {
private:
    using b_base = std::string;
public:
    // was int f() const { return b.size(); }
    int f() const { return b_base::size(); }

private:
    int a;
    float c;
    friend Data* getBaseDataPtrFromString(std::string* mStringMember);
};

Data* getBaseDataPtrFromString(std::string* mStringMember) {
    return static_cast<Data*>(mStringMember);
}
```

Comment: If you are dealing with literal types this also works in constexpr scopes because it has no reinterpret_cast.

Comment: I've accepted the answer using `offsetof`, but I'm curious about this one - I don't understand how it works, could you explain it further? Is inheritance required? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, inheritance is required for this to work. It works because `static_cast` knows how to properly adjust pointers from base types to derived types.

Comment: Here's a post by Raymond Chen that shows the same trick: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that some `ptr`  is in fact the address of some `s->b` (which is not always true) you might try to use [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

```
Data* getBaseDataPtrFromString(std::string* ptr) {
   void* ad = (char*)ptr - offsetof(Data,b);
   return reinterpret_cast<Data*>(ad);
}
```

BTW, GCC has a [builtin_offsetof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html) to help implementing the `offsetof` macro (notably in more general cases than those required by the standard). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400116/841108).