# Efficiently and elegantly returning emplaced unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, return, unique-ptr, emplace

I found out ([thanks to a StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909837/standard-way-to-find-base-address-of-struct-from-a-member?noredirect=1#comment33188946_21909837)) a security flaw in my code:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;

template<class... TS> Item& create(TS&&... mArgs)
{
    auto item(new Item(std::forward<TS>(mArgs)...);
    items.emplace_back(item); // Possible exception and memory leak
    return *item;
}
```

Basically, allocating the `Item` with a raw `new` may leak memory if the `emplace_back` throws.

The solution is never using a raw `new`, but using a `std::unique_ptr` right in the method body.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;

template<class... TS> Item& create(TS&&... mArgs)
{
    auto item(std::make_unique<Item>(std::forward<TS>(mArgs)...);
    items.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    return *item; // `item` was moved, this is invalid!
}
```

As you can see, returning `item` is invalid, as I had to move `item` using `std::move` to emplace it into the `items` container.

I can't think of a solution that requires storing `item`'s address in an additional variable. The original (buggy) solution is however very concise and easy to read.

**Is there a more elegant way of returning an `std::unique_ptr` that was moved for emplacement in a container?**

Comment: `return *items.back();`

Comment: Why do you return a reference to something inside `unique_ptr` in the first place?

Comment: What if that `items` vector suddenly disappears?

Comment: As an aside, note that the code only offers basic exception guarantees: if `emplace_back` throws, the parameters will have already been moved from.

Comment: @avakar, is there a way to address this issue, too?

Comment: @avakar @VittorioRomeo I don't think it's a problem, the temporaries passed into it were going to be destroyed anyway. As for copies, it would be only a problem if copy constructor was non-`const` for some of the parameters.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo In cases of extreme paranoia, I suppose you could reserve space in `items` before touching the parameters - then you'd only lose information if the `Item` constructor throws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may write:

```
template<class... TS>
Item& create(TS&&... mArgs)
{
    items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item>(std::forward<TS>(mArgs)...));
    return *items.back();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Caching the reference before the emplace is a more generally applicable option (e.g., for non-vector containers):

```
template<class... TS> Item& create(TS&&... mArgs)
{
    auto item = std::make_unique<Item>(std::forward<TS>(mArgs)...);
    auto& foo = *item;
    items.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    return foo; // This *is* valid.
}
```

Comment: thought i think you can still have problems if emplace throws, andrej had recently an article where he suggests calling .reserve() first

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl That's basically the issue we're discussing in the comments on the OP - although no one really made it clear. This is enough to provide the basic exception safety guarantee: if `emplace_back` throws, arguments passed to `create` as rvalues will be left in the moved-from condition with their guts torn out and destroyed. If it's desired to provide the strong exception safety guarantee, then space in the vector should be reserved `items.reserve(items.size() + 1)` *before* anything else happens, especially the potential movement of arguments into the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Correction: this function *can't* provide the strong exception safety guarantee because there's no way to ensure that the `Item` constructor either succeeds or does not modify the `mArgs`. You can guarantee that (a) the container is unchanged if an exception is thrown, and (b) the arguments are unmodified unless the `Item` constructor throws. If the strong guarantee is critical, the function would have to be modified to accept a `unique_ptr` param and simply move it into the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged C++11, and other answers suggesting `make_unique` fail to mention that it is a C++14 feature.  I believe this C++11 approach also resolves the leak.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Item
{
   int a, b;
   Item(int aa, int bb) : a{aa}, b{bb} { }
};

static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;

template <class... Ts> Item& create(Ts&&... args)
{
    items.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Item>{new Item(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)});
    return *items.back();
}

int main()
{
    Item& x = create(1, 2);
    std::cout << "( " << x.a << ", " << x.b << " )" << std::endl;
}
```

This should be safe because `emplace_back()` cannot be called until a `unique_ptr<Item>` was already constructed, so even if `emplace_back()` does throw, your `Item` is already managed by the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Where is this `unique_ptr<Item>` constructed in `create`? I'm not seeing it. Did you mean to write `items.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Item>{new Item(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)});`?

Comment: I guess I was thinking that a `unique_ptr<Item>` would have to be implicitly constructed from the arguments to emplace_back, but I see now that that's not right.  Yes, your suggestion looks better.