# Storing and recycling heap-allocated variable size objects without malloc and free

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, memory-management, malloc

I want to store polymorphic objects with variable size that derive from the `Base` class on the free store.

I also want to store a `bool` value in the same memory block, right before the memory reserved for the derived object.

```
/* 
    Desired memory layout for storage of one object:

    base address
    v
    |      |                                   |     
    | bool | . . . . . variable size . . . . . |               
    |      |                                   |
           ^                                   ^
           object address                      end address
*/
```

The first thing I tried was creating a `struct` with a `bool` member and an aligned storage of a template-passed parameter `std::size_t` size.

I've tried using `offsetof` and `reinterpret_cast` like in [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909837/standard-way-to-find-base-address-of-struct-from-a-member), but the program always crashed and I wasn't able to debug the error.

Therefore, I tried using `std::malloc` and `std::free`, and the program works as expected. 
However I'm now lacking C++ `new`/`delete` safety and I don't have any kind of alignment.

I would really like to find a way to re-implement the code below using `std::aligned_storage` or something that assures me the code will work on any platform and will be standard-compliant.

I want to store the *additional* `bool` in memory before the actual object.

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() { } };
struct Der1 : Base { char c[100]; };
struct Der2 : Base { char c[200]; };

template<typename TBase> struct LocalRecycler
{
    // Allocated, but unused pointers, that can be recycled
    std::vector<void*> recyclable;

    // Upon destruction, free all allocated memory
    // No need to call the destructors, as I'm 100% sure recyclable 
    // pointers alredy destroyed their inner object
    ~LocalRecycler() 
    { 
        for(auto p : recyclable) free(p); 
    }

    // I'm omitting variadic template parameters for generic construction,
    // as they are not relevant to the question
    template<typename T> T* create() 
    {
         void* objAddress;

         // If we have some space that is already allocated, use it
         // Otherwise, allocate new space
         if(!recyclable.empty())
         {
             objAddress = recyclable.back();
             recyclable.pop_back();
         }
         else 
         { 
             // Note how I'm not taking into account alignment here
             // That's one reason why I would like to avoid using `std::malloc`
             objAddress = std::malloc(sizeof(bool) + sizeof(T));
         }

         // Construct a `bool` at the beginning of the allocated memory block
         // Construct a `T' after the bool
         new (objAddress + 0)            bool{true};
         new (objAddress + sizeof(bool)) T{};

         return reinterpret_cast<T*>(objAddress + sizeof(bool));
    }

    void recycle(void* mPtr)
    {
        // Destroy the inner object
        TBase* basePtr{reinterpret_cast<TBase*>(mPtr + sizeof(bool))};
        basePtr->TBase::~TBase();

        // The memory block can now be reused
        recyclable.emplace_back(mPtr);
    }
};
```

The above code seems to work properly in my program.

What I am asking is: **how can I "convert" the above C-style code to modern C++11/C++14 code, also taking care of alignment?**

Comment: You have ERROR in your code: When you take a memory in `objAddress = recyclable.back();` you are not checking if memory is big enough for `sizeof(T)` - worse: in current design you can't do that...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: I make sure all the objects in my `LocalRecycler<TBase>` store the same type `T`. I cannot templatize `LocalRecycler` with the type `T` because I need a `std::vector` of `LocalRecycler` objects that share the same base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that creating a class like the following do the job:

```
template <typename T>
struct ClassWithBool
{
    bool b;
    T t;
};
```

And then you may use `std::allocator` to allocate/destroy the object.

Comment: I do not know what `T` is until I create it with `LocalRecycler::create<T>(...)`.

Comment: I don't see the problem, you may have in `create<T>`, `std::allocator<ClassWithBool<T> > myAllocator;` and call `myAllocator->allocate` or `construct` to replace your `malloc` and *placement `new`*.

Comment: I understand now. It may work, but I need a reliable way to get `b` from a pointer to `t`, and `t` from a pointer to `b`. I can do this easily with `std::malloc`-allocated objects because I know there's no alignment, so simple pointer arithmetic can let me get the members I need - I will try using `offsetof` again, but as I mentioned in the question I couldn't get it to work the first time.

Comment: It seems that it would be cleaner to implement an allocator (with state). (And I don't understand the use of the `bool`).