# offsetof macro in msvc C and pointer members

Tags: c

I'm translating some C code from gcc to be msvc compatible. Ran into a problem where the offsetof macro from cstddef cannot get the offset of any pointer types (while it works in the gcc version and in msvc++). example:

```
struct banana{
    int blah;
    void* wat;
};

static void test()
{
    int pos = offsetof(struct banana, wat);
}
```

it claims "expression must have integral type". Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: `cstddef` is a C++-only header. Did you mean `stddef.h` ? Post your exact MCVE and compiler command

Comment: oh yes replacing it with stddef.h fixed it

Comment: The link you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400116/what-is-the-purpose-and-return-type-of-the-builtin-offsetof-operator